# Baseurl behavior differs between localhost and github pages in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, base-url

I am developing a static site using `Jekyll`, to be deployed on `github pages`. I am facing issues using the baseurl in the configuration file. Here is an extract of my `_config.yml`:

```
baseurl: "/blog"
url: "http://remidoolaeghe.github.io"
```

When ran locally at http://localhost:4000/blog/, everything is fine. The html pages are found, the resources (images, css, js) are loaded and applied on the pages.

Once deployed on `Github Pages`, I would expect to have the site available at: http://remidoolaeghe.github.io/blog
But the actual URL is http://remidoolaeghe.github.io.

It seems the baseurl is not used by the `Jekyll` on `Github Pages`. The HTML pages are not at the expected URLs, neither any resources is (css, images, etc). Nothing based on baseurl is loaded by the browser, as you can see here:

[image]

I have checked the used `Jekyll version`. I use the same as `Github Pages`(2.4.0).

Have I missed something?

My `Github`repo can be found [here](https://github.com/remidoolaeghe/remidoolaeghe.github.io).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative to redirecting to `/blog` is:

**1. GitHub Pages Redirect from**

GitHub pages allow for the `redirect-from` Jekyll plugin as mentioned [here](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/). You could use their [plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) and redirect from there. Although as it's built for preventing old links from going to 404, this might not be what you want given your use-case.

**2. Manually have meta refresh tag in your root `index.html`.**

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/blog/">
```

You'll want that tag in a `<head> </head>`. This will tell the any request to your root url point to the `index.html` stored at `/blog/`. This is a fast way to doing it, similar to how `.htaccess` [rewrites are done](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Transparently_redirect_your_root_directory_to_a_subdirectory), except GitHub Pages doesn't support .htaccess for security reasons. At that point also check if you're getting `404`s for some resources and update their paths accordingly, maybe with the help of `site.baseurl`, as another answer explains. `baseurl` is not what you think it does. See [this post by Parker about the baseurl variable](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/).

**In short,**
I think your best option is to use the second one, short of creating a gh-pages `blog` repository and moving your site there. In fact, **if you did move to a a separate blog repo** which might make things complicated, you still need to redirect `http://remidoolaeghe.github.io` to point to `http://remidoolaeghe.github.io/blog` or else people who visit `http://remidoolaeghe.github.io` and not the `/blog` link get a blank page only.

Comment: I see what you mean. You helped me wonder about what I really wanted. Actually, I wish to have a "blog" part on my website, and a "non-blog" part. I think I'll have to move to a blog github repo, so that I can still have a non-blog part linkable (with hyperlinks) from blog part and vice-versa. Do you think I can have one repo that generate a part of the site reachable at http://remidoolaeghe.github.io, another one pointing at  http://remidoolaeghe.github.io/blog and make the illusion this is a single website from the visitor's point of view ?

Comment: Well you certainly can have a normal GitHub Pages repo that is reachable at the normal github.io domain, then have hyperlinks that point to your second repo which is a `gh-pages` repo named `blog`: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/

but aside from having to push twice maybe it's just better to have it all in one repo and have posts that go to blog, unless you feel it's better managing 2 repos

Comment: of course the visitor will see it as a single website, provided you have same styles and designs, which I assume you don't want an identical one given you want 2 repos? (because if you did want identical design you might be better off managing one repo?)

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to manage 2 repos, of course. In a perfect world, I'd like my posts (and an index page) going to a /blog directory  so that "/blog" appears in URL. Maybe should I just use the [permalink](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) option in the config file to have my posts and my index available at /blog/suffix?

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe I would go with the permalink option. (that's what I am doing actually)

Answer (score 2):

The `baseurl` is used by jekyll to construct url relative to the root of your web site. eg : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/main.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">`.

It is not used by github page to generate your site path.

In order to reach your blog at http://remidoolaeghe.github.io/blog you need to move it in a **blog** repository.

Comment: This is strange, because my site deployed locally works fine. And it is not in a /blog folder, just in its default _site folder. Where is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my `kitty image` shown cutely in localhost but missing in github pages with 404 error and the pathname is incorrectly missing `baseurl`. I solved it in [kitty-image-problem-solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954620/kitty-image-is-missing-in-welcome-to-jekyll-post-but-shown-at-index-md-and-about.md).

In short, in order for your /img/avatar.png to show up in your _posts/ posts, you should do

```
   ![Paris]( {{"/img/avatar.png" | relative_url }})
```

The document of `relative_url` is at [jykyll-liquid-filters](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)