# Jumbotron Background Image in React prod build does not render

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, babeljs, jsx

My image is not rendering in my React App using Bootstrap 4.3 after running `npm run build`.

I have moved the image to the Public Dir (`/images/bg.jpg`). I can get it to render properly in the Dev Environment (`npm start`). But if I execute `npm run build` and then deploy to GH-Pages, the image does not render in the Jumbotron (https://jobu206.github.io/hotdog-usa).

**React Component & CSS**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style.css";

class Jumbotron extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Jumbotron;
```

```css
.jumbotron {
  background: url("/images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 60vh;
}
```

Expectation is that the Dev build and the Prod Build would be in sync and look identical.

Answer (score 0):

When rendering JSX you need specify CSS classes via the [`className`](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects) prop, rather than via `class` as you currently are doing:

```
class Jumbotron extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      { /* replace class with className */ }
      <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div className="container">

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh...yes. Forgot about that. Thanks for calling that one out. I've just changed. However, the problem still remains. When I navigate to the deployed app on GH-Pages, the image is not rendered but does render when using the Dev build.

Comment: Any chance you can show the config yml that you're using? Are you setting the `baseurl`, and if so to what?

Comment: Sorry, not sure where that's located. I don't see a config yml in my directory tree.

Comment: Ok - perhaps this will help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209076/baseurl-behavior-differs-between-localhost-and-github-pages-in-jekyll

Comment: Yeah, that definitely sounds like my problem. I added that metadata but now the page just goes into continual refresh mode.